# Is the speedup from branch prediction dependent on the predicate's complexity?

Tags: c++, branch-prediction

Suppose I have some function `IsTrue()` which returns a `bool`. If the programmer decides that `IsTrue()` will usually return `true`, she might employ GCC's [`__builtin_expect`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#index-g_t_005f_005fbuiltin_005fexpect-3860) or similar to speed up instructions in those typical cases.

Taking the following 2 examples:

```
// example 1
const bool result = IsTrue();
if (__builtin_expect(result, true))
  // do something
  ;

// example 2
if (__builtin_expect(IsTrue(), true))
  // do something
  ;
```

Assuming that `IsTrue` is non-trivial, is there any difference between these? Does placing `IsTrue()` inside the `__builtin_expect` parameter list cause the instruction cache to be evaluated *before* the result of `IsTrue` is known, or does branch prediction only apply *after* the result of `IsTrue` is calculated?

Comment: Just as a side note: If the predicate is *complex* (probably involving its own branching), the relative cost for the original branch will be diminishing anyway.

Comment: I think you're confusing branch prediction on the CPU and prediction hinting on the compiler.  Branch Prediction only happens when a CPU sees a branch instruction and decides whether we should actually take it. Prediction hinting tells compiler that there is an ideal arrangement of branching code to get better predicting behavior at runtime. Your code samples are effectively the same as in both cases the compiler must evaluate the function and store the result in some kind of variable. The first example is just making it explicit.

Answer (score 3):

All modern processors employ superscalar pipeline which pre-computes instructions following the one that is actually executed. By using `__builtin_expect`, the compiler reorders instructions so that the expected (likely) path won't use jumps which cause the superscalar pipeline to miss and therefore makes all pre-computed results useless.

EDIT: this is of course simplified. Modern processors also have branch prediction so they try to predict which path the code would follow but the path without jumps is still preferred (it is also better for cache because the executed code path is compact). Also note that these changes in speed are usually quite marginal and you don't need to bother if your code is not extremely often executed or really needs as much speed as possible.

Comment: I would prefer optimizations that eliminate branching instead of specific hinting for control flow. The fastest branch is the one you don't have to take.

Answer (score 1):

As the GCC documentation says, prefer building with profile-guided optimization (PGO, `-fprofile-generate` followed by running testcases and rebuilding with `-fprofile-use`) to writing with `__builtin_expect`.

The CPU's built-in branch prediction will cache most of the branches in the program's "typical" execution paths. Static branch prediction makes a difference mainly when it provides strong data on *all* the branches, so when the compiler has a choice between doing one of several tests first, it can arrange the most efficient sequence. This considers not only what values resolve to, but which `else if` statement gets picked most frequently.

`__builtin_expect` will seldom make a difference. For branchy programs, `-fprofile-use` will usually provide an instant 10-30% boost at no programming effort.

> Does placing `IsTrue()` inside the `__builtin_expect` parameter list cause the instruction cache to be evaluated before the result of `IsTrue` is known, or does branch prediction only apply after the result of `IsTrue` is calculated?

`__builtin_expect` happens at compile-time. The instruction cache doesn't even exist yet. The compiler will guess that `IsTrue` is `true`, and then at runtime, the CPU will make another, better-informed guess.